# Concat certain fields of a String line after split

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, split, concatenation

I have a file in Json-like format that contains hundreds of tweets (all have 5 fields):

```json
[...]

{
  "idTweet":"943959778006589441",
  "text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...",
  "idAuthor":"912276331584421889",
  "idOriginal":"0",
  "origAuthor":"0"
}

[...]
```

I convert the contents of the file into an RDD to work with it

```scala
val testRDD = spark.sparkContext.textFile("json-like_file.txt")
```

And I split each String line:

```scala
val tweets = testRDD.map(t => t.split("\",\""))
  .map(fields => (fields(0), fields(1), fields(2), fields(3), fields(4)))
```

Giving result (scheme) [ej. 1]:

```
field(0):  {"idTweet":"943959778006589441"
field(1):  "text":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..."
field(2):  "idAuthor":"912276331584421889"
field(3):  "idOriginal":"0"
field(4):  "origAuthor":"0"}
```

All good as long as the tweet line contain errors like the following on texts:

```json
{
  "idTweet":"943959778006589441",
  "text":"Lorem ipsum","dolor sit","amet","...",
  "idAuthor":"912276331584421889",
  "idOriginal":"0",
  "origAuthor":"0"
}
```

If I slpit as before, it divides it in this way:

```
field(0):  {"idTweet":"943959778006589441"
field(1):  "text":"Lorem ipsum"
field(2):  "dolor sit"
field(3):  "amet"
field(4):  "..."}
```

How could I concatenate certain fields to join them in one (field text) after split the string? Like [ej. 1] result.

Comment: Looks like json file. Why don't you use json parsing ?

Answer (score 0):

You said that the format was "Json-like", which implies it is not actual *JSON*. The following blurb:

```
{
  "idTweet":"943959778006589441",
  "text":"Lorem ipsum","dolor sit","amet","...",
  "idAuthor":"912276331584421889",
  "idOriginal":"0",
  "origAuthor":"0"
}
```

is **not** valid *JSON*, and so if you were to use a *JSON* parser, it would error out accordingly and could be handled as you so choose.

If the format is *JSON*-esque, but not actually *JSON*, this strikes me as a case where you need to custom-validate the format on the way in, and handle it accordingly.

In the case of the above blurb, it should be determined to be invalid in your format and instead marked invalid in a way of your choosing, with the *Spark* job proceeding on to the next record in the `RDD`.